# "What more do you want to buy" Vs "What else do you want to buy"

Tags: british-english

When having a shopping with my brother or friend and I want to him if they buy more things after we bought some, then what's of these two is more common in British English?

> "What **more** do you want to buy?"

or

> "What **else** do you want to buy?"

In addition, is it valid to say > "What **more / else** do you want?" (without detailing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Superficially, they're equivalent. But *idiomatically* (for no particular reason that I can think of), using ***more*** carries stronger implications of ***exasperation*** (I think what you've already had is excessive - how can you still want *more?*).

So if we suppose the question is being asked by an attentive sales assistant, he'd definitely avoid ***more*** and [deferentially] ask what ***else*** you [*would like*, not *want*]. But if you're accompanying the shopper (as a friend, not some other shopper who's fed up with waiting for you to finish your purchase, so he can pay and get out of the shop! :) just choose your word according to what you *mean*, as outlined above.

---

I think these two charts clearly reflect that idiomatic distinction. Firstly, note the [very strong preference](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What%20more%20would%20you%20like%2CWhat%20else%20would%20you%20like&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWhat%20more%20would%20you%20like%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWhat%20else%20would%20you%20like%3B%2Cc0) for ***else*** over ***more*** in the context of more explicitly "deferential" ***...would you like?***

[image]

And just look at [how far that preference reverses](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What%20more%20do%20you%20want%2CWhat%20else%20do%20you%20want&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWhat%20more%20do%20you%20want%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWhat%20else%20do%20you%20want%3B%2Cc0), in more "general" (including "hostile, exasperated") contexts that might be reflected by (often, "blunt-spoken") ***...do you want?***

[image]

In short, although I very much doubt there's a meaningful *explanation* as to how this idiomatic distinction came about, it's definitely quite strong. Which means *many / most native speakers would notice* if you used the inappropriate version in any given context.

---

You might try to remember the distinction by thinking of Oliver Twist being castigated when he asks for more porridge: *Surely you can't want **more**, boy!* as opposed to euphemistic condom-selling barbers of yesteryear: *Will there be anything **else**, sir? Something for the weekend, perhaps?*

Just a thought - but honestly, for all I know the preference really *does* stem from that well-known scene in *Oliver Twist*. It's been part of our culture for a *long* time.

Comment: Thank you for the nice and detailed answer. Just to be sure, is it OK to say "what else / more do you want?" (without addition of the "to + verb" in the end. "What else to you want **to buy**" for example). The same question might be about "what else would you like" or "What else would you like **to**.

Comment: I think the same implications of exasperation could attend **else**.

Comment: @Conceivableassessment: No, you can't validly ask ***What else would you like to?***, because ***to*** in this context is an "infinitive marker" (for a ***verb***, which must appear immediately after it). But in general, there's no requirement to identify the *specific* wanted thing / action (with a noun / verb) in the contexts being covered here. So "non-specific" ***What do you want**?* could be asked with a range of implied continuations, such as ***...from me?, ...to eat?, ...him to say?,*** etc.